# MVC Razor if else not displaing date

Tags: date, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, conditional-statements

This makes no sense to me!  I have a simple conditional statement that is working, but it will not display the **else** date.  It will display that bold End Date:.  I'm testing if the date is default and if true, display current admitted.  But if the end date is not null, I want to display the date.

```
@if(Model.allBuyins.Where(z => z.Counter == 2).Select(z => z.End_NHdate).First() == default(DateTime))
{
   <strong>Currently Admitted</strong>                                                     
}
else
{
    <strong>End Date:</strong>
    string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Model.allBuyins.Where(z => z.Counter == 2).Select(z => z.Begin_NHdate).First()));                                                      
}
```

If I copy the date in my else and move it outside my coditional statement, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an Html tag around your string.Format() function and it should work just fine.

```
  <span>@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(default(DateTime)));</span>
```

The reason I see, is, that the statement is getting evaluated but the it's not being rendered as text in html. But when you prefixed it with @ sign  Razor treats it as rendering stuff so it does appear in generated html.

Comment: Thanks.  Now it makes sense.    The semicolon is not needed at the end of the string.format